# Tailwind missing lots of styles

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, tailwind-3, laravel-breeze

I built a new site using Laravel Breeze with Vue as a base. Now have found there to be lots of missing classes from what's defined within the Tailwind docs.

**Edit**: To clarify these are classes I tried to use in a static fashion e.g. `<div class="outline-green>"` and `<div class="outline-green-100>"` after seeing them in the docs and they didn't render the styles.

For example there's only a handful of classes tied to the color green e.g. `text-green-600` and `bg-green`. Also there's no outline classes at all except for 4: `focus:outline-none`, `focus:outline:focus`, `focus:ountline-2:focus`, and `.focus:outline-red-500:focus`

Initially noticed this on version 3.3.6 and have updated to 3.4.1, re-built and still seeing the same thing.

I have tried updating to the latest version
[image]

This is my config, default that came out of breeze except the addition of the forms plugin
[image]

Confirmed colors and variants are defined in the package[image]

This is a shot of the newly attempted  build of the css showing lots of variants in certain classes, but they all have gaps, there's not one example of it having generated all classes: `50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 950` [image]

Comment: Consider checking you have used the classes that you expect to be in the compiled CSS,  the `content` file globs sufficiently cover files that use Tailwind classes and that you have not [use string interpolation/concatenation to build class names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).

Comment: Yes, I have attempted to use the missing classes and they didn't render the expected styles, that's when I noticed the discrepancy in the docs vs what I was getting.

Comment: Are you running `npm run dev` continuously, or at least after you've added new classes? Tailwind will only include classes it has seen you use.

Comment: @ceejayoz wow, I don't know how I didn't encounter that as an "issue" until this point.. yeah just re-running npm run dev resolved it. Do you want to create an answer and I'll accept that? Otherwise, I'll create one and reference you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind monitors the files in your `tailwind.config.js` (in your case, mostly Blade and Vue files) for usage of Tailwind classes. It then renders a CSS file with *only* those classes; this keeps the file size down, and also permits things like [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) for classes.

As a result, using *new* classes Tailwind hasn't seen before won't do anything unless you're running `npm run dev` during development (or you ran `npm run build` for prod).